# Haskell Hermite polynomials implementation

Tags: haskell, math, recursion, hermite

Haskell allows to represent recurrent functions in a very concise way. For example, infinite list, that contains Fibonacci numbers can be defined as follows:

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

I am dealing with 'probabilists' Hermite polynomials, which have the following recursion relation:

[image]

What would be the optimal way to construct the infinite list of n-th Hermite polynomials for given x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write it as:

```
hermite :: (Enum n, Num n) => n -> [n]
hermite x = s
    where s@(_:ts) = 1 : x : zipWith3 (\hn2 hn1 n1 -> x*hn1 - n1*hn2) s ts [1..]
```

where the first items `1 : x : ...` are the first elements of the `hermite` (you can fill in other values).

For the next one, we zip the original values `s` (so that starts with `H0`), the tail `ts` of `s` (that starts with `H1`) and the index (that starts with `2`, `3`, ...) and perform an operation `x*hn1 - x*hn2` (`nh1` stands for *H<sub>n-1</sub>*, and `nh2` stands for *H<sub>n-2</sub>*), and so we calculate the next element each time.

The first 11 values for `x = 0.75` are:

```
Prelude> take 11 (hermite 0.75)
[1.0,0.75,-0.4375,-1.828125,-5.859375e-2,7.2685546875,5.744384765625,-39.30303955078125,-69.68797302246094,262.1583366394043,823.8105096817017]
```

So the first value is 1, the second `x`, the third one `x*x-2`, the fourth one `x*x*x-2*x-3*x`, and so on.

That being said, if I recall correctly, the recursion formula of the Hermite polynomials is:

*H<sub>n</sub>(x) = 2×x×H<sub>n-1</sub>(x)-2×(n-1)H<sub>n-2</sub>(x)*

instead of the one quoted in the question.

In that case the formula is thus:

```
hermite :: (Enum n, Num n) => n -> [n]
hermite x = s
    where s@(_:ts) = 1 : 2 * x : zipWith3 helper s ts [1..]
          helper hn2 hn1 n1 = 2 * (x * hn1 - n1 * hn2)
```

Then the first 11 values are:

```
Prelude> take 11 (hermite 0.75)
[1.0,1.5,0.25,-5.625,-9.9375,30.09375,144.515625,-144.3515625,-2239.74609375,-1049.994140625,38740.4384765625]
```

Which is correct acording to this [Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html):

> H<sub>0</sub> = 1
>
> H<sub>1</sub> = 2*x
>
> H<sub>2</sub> = 4˙x<sup>2</sup> - 2
>
> H<sub>3</sub> = 8˙x<sup>3</sup> - 4˙x
>
> H<sub>4</sub> = 16˙x<sup>4</sup> - 48˙x<sup>2</sup> + 12

Which maps exactly on the values we obtained:

```
Prelude> let x = 0.75 in [1,2*x,4*x*x-2,8*x*x*x-4*x,16*x*x*x*x-48*x*x+12]
[1.0,1.5,0.25,0.375,-9.9375]
```

Comment: Yup, I made a typo in my formula (n instead of n-1 on the rhs), now it's corrected. However, the formula you talking about is a so-called 'physicists' Hermite polynomial, which I don't need. Could you please correct your answer according to the change I've made?